# How to use declaration for 3th party module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using [`fingerprintjs2`](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) library, which has incomplete and incompatible declaration in [definitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/fingerprintjs2/index.d.ts)

I choose to write my own declaration in my project and I'm struggling with loading that declaration in code. I'm still getting error

> Cannot find module 'fingerprintjs2'

in this import statement

```
import Fingerprint2, { TCallback, TComponent } from 'fingerprintjs2';
```

my declaration is written as isolated module

```
// ./src/@types/fingerprintjs2/index.d.ts

// ...some other exported types

export type TComponent = {
    key: string;
    value: string | number | boolean | string[];
};

export type TCallback = (components: TComponent[]) => void;

export default interface fingerprintjs2 {
    get(callback: TCallback): void;
    get(options: TOptions, callback: TCallback): void;
    getPromise(options: TOptions): Promise<TComponent[]>;
}
```

my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./dist",
        "lib": ["dom", "es5", "scripthost"],
        "module": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "paths": { "*": ["./src/@types*"] },
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

I did not find clear explanation of how this shall work. Can you please give me an advice? I appreciate your help.

I'm using Typescript 3.1.6 in Webstorm 2018.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with resolving the module, I've changed **tscongif.json** *compiler options*

```
++ "moduleResolution": "node",
-- "paths": { "*": ["./src/@types*"] },
++ "paths": { "*": ["./node_modules/*", "./src/@types/*"] },
```

And then the module was resolved.

I've got an error, that the module exports just type, which was true, I've exported an `interface`. I had to firstly implement that interface and then export the implemented value. Like this

```
// declare const value with interface
declare const fingeprint: fingerprintjs2;
// export that const value
export default fingeprint;
```

now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up typeRoots so that it will pick up your custom types folder.

source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

something like this should work:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "src/@types"
]
```

Comment: It seems like `typeRoots` is for global declarations see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-369783776